# how to retrieve unmatched data from two table

Tags: sql-server

I created a table `managers` :

```
create table managers(
    ManagerId int identity(1,1) not for replication not null,
    M_name varchar(20),
    Salary varchar(20),
    joining_year varchar(20),
    city varchar(20),
    IdCode int
)
```

then insert some data into this table:

```
ManagerId   | M_name  |  Salary  | joining_year |  city   |  IdCode
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1          | riva    | 50000    | 1998         |  pune   | 4
2          | tanmay  | 48500    | 1990         |gurgaon  | 2
3          | david   | 49000    | 2001         | goa     | 2
4          | null    | null     | null         | null    | null
5          | null    | null     | null         | null    | null
6          | dannial | 52185    | 2010         | kanpur  | 6
```

And have second table `managerEmp`

```
create table managerEmp(
    employeId int identity(1,1) not for replication not null,
    family_member varchar(20),
    wife_name varchar(20),
    age int
)
```

I have some data in that table:

```
employeId | family_member |wife_name | age
--------------------------------------------
1        | 6             |mrs.kapoor| 31
2        | 5             |mrs.mishra| 25
3        | null          |nll       | null
4        | 2             |mrs.khan  | 21
5        | 4             |mrs.bajaj | 22
```

Now, I want to select uncommon data from that table. The result would be:

```
M_name | Salary | city | wife_name | age
-----------------------------------------
null   | null   | null | mrs.khan  | 21
null   | null   | null | mrs.bajaj | 22
dannial| 52185  |kanpur| null      |null
```

Comment: What is "uncommon data"?

Comment: I have to say, either your database design or your data is really bad. There's basically just NULL rows in both of your tables. Also storing age instead of birthday... when do you update it?

Comment: Looks like uncommon stuff is where wife data is not present in managerEmp table for a manager or when manager data is NULL in the manager table.

Answer (score 1):

Query based on your output:

```
SELECT M_name,Salary,city,wife_name,age FROM managers LEFT JOIN managerEmp 
ON managers.ManagerId =managerEmp.employeId 
WHERE M_name is NULL OR employeId  IS NULL
```

Link to SQL fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e1776/1